# Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtBlockExpression

Tags: kotlin

My code is working but my test is not working when I use the deprecated version of kotlin 1.3. When I change the version to 1.6 the test class works normally. The problem is that all the code in my project's modules is still at version 1.3 and all the code is still working. What do I need to change to get my code past kotlin version 1.3?
Error on console:
Kotlin: [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtBlockExpression

````
The root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$typeMappingConfiguration$1.processErrorType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:127)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:355)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genStatement(ExpressionCodegen.java:454)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:411)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1839)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:86)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:646)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:483)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:260)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:165)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:136)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:200)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:170)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:88)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:132)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:305)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:289)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:119)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:138)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:70)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:140)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.invokeLowerings(CodegenFactory.kt:119)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.runLowerings(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:373)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:129)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:60)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:172)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:91)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1547)

at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)

at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)

at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error type encountered: (org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.ErrorUtils$UninferredParameterTypeConstructor@d084bd5..org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.ErrorUtils$UninferredParameterTypeConstructor@d084bd5) (FlexibleTypeImpl).

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$typeMappingConfiguration$1.processErrorType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:127)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.DescriptorBasedTypeSignatureMappingKt.mapType(descriptorBasedTypeSignatureMapping.kt:81)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:279)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$writeGenericArguments$1$1.invoke(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:370)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$writeGenericArguments$1$1.invoke(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:369)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$Companion.writeGenericArguments(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:1502)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.writeGenericArguments(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:369)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.writeGenericArguments(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:359)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.writeGenericType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:312)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.access$writeGenericType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:84)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$mapType$1.invoke(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:282)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$mapType$1.invoke(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:279)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.DescriptorBasedTypeSignatureMappingKt.mapType(descriptorBasedTypeSignatureMapping.kt:54)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapType(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:279)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapTypeArgument(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:229)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.getOrCreateCallGenerator(ExpressionCodegen.java:2945)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.getOrCreateCallGenerator(ExpressionCodegen.java:2926)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2691)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:42)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:68)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:128)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:121)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallReceiver.putSelector(CallReceiver.java:168)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:128)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:121)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putReceiverAndInlineMarkerIfNeeded(ExpressionCodegen.java:2812)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2720)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2700)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:42)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:68)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:128)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:121)

at org.jetbra

ins.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1341)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.generateBlock(ExpressionCodegen.java:1280)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitBlockExpression(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:56)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CodegenStatementVisitor.visitBlockExpression(CodegenStatementVisitor.java:22)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBlockExpression.accept(KtBlockExpression.java:79)

at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:333)

... 46 more```

And here my unit test

And my code below, the error happens in my setup function

```@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class ServiceTest {

    private val reasonRepository: ReasonRepository = mock()

    private val productRepository: ProductRepository = mock()

    private val productTagRepository: ProductTagRepository = mock()

    private val partnerRepository: PartnerRepository = mock()

    private val productService: ProductService = mock()

    private val loanRepository: LoanRepository = mock()

    private val financialProductTagRepository: FinancialProductTagRepository = mock()

    private lateinit var strategyOne: StrategyOne

    private lateinit var strategyTwo: StrategyTwo

    private lateinit var strategyThree: StrategyThree

    private lateinit var strategyFour: StrategyFour

    private lateinit var strategyFive: StrategyFive

    private lateinit var strategySix: StrategySix

    private lateinit var strategySeven: StrategySeven

    private lateinit var service: Service

    private lateinit var strategy: List<Strategy>

    private lateinit var serviceHelper: ServiceHelper


    companion object {

        private val loanTypeLow = BigDecimal(2000)

        private val loanTypeMedium = BigDecimal(2001)

        private val loanTypeHigh = BigDecimal(100001)

    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        serviceHelper = ServiceHelper(productRepository, productService)
        strategyOne = StrategyOne(serviceHelper)
        strategyTwo = StrategyTwo(serviceHelper)
        strategyThree = StrategyThree(serviceHelper)
        strategyFour = StrategyFour(serviceHelper)
        strategyFive = StrategyFive(serviceHelper)
        strategySix = StrategySix(serviceHelper)
        strategySeven = StrategySeven(serviceHelper)
        strategy =
            listOf(
                strategyOne,
                strategyTwo,
                strategyThree,
                strategyFour,
                strategyFive,
                strategySix,
                strategySeven
            )
        service = Service(Strategy, serviceHelper, reasonRepository)

        val loanOne = Loan(
            id = 1,
            name = LoanType.LOW
        )

        val loanTwo = Loan(
            id = 2,
            name = LoanType.MEDIUM
        )

        val loanThree = Loan(
            id = 3,
            name = LoanType.HIGH
        )

        val reasonOne = Reason(
            id = 1,
            title = "Bar 1",
            type = FINANCING,
            loan = setOf(loanThree),
            index = 1
        )

        val reasonTwo = Reason(
            id = 2,
            title = "Bar 2",
            type = FINANCING,
            loan = setOf(loanThree),
            index = 2
        )

        val reasonThree = Reason(
            id = 3,
            title = "Bar 3",
            type = FINANCING,
            loan = setOf(loanTwo, loanThree),
            index = 4
        )

        val reasonFour = Reason(
            id = 4,
            title = "Bar 4",
            type = FINANCING,
            loan = setOf(loanTwo, loanThree),
            index = 3
        )

        val reasonFive = Reason(
            id = 5,
            title = "Bar 5",
            type = OTHER,
            loan = setOf(loanTwo)
        )

        val reasonSix = Reason(
            id = 6,
            title = "Bar 6",
            type = OTHER,
            loan = setOf(loanTwo)
        )

        val reasonSeven = Reason(
            id = 7,
            title = "Outro",
            type = OTHER,
            loan = setOf(loanTwo, loanThree),
            index = 5
        )

        val tag = ProductTag(
            id = 1,
            title = "Foo 1",
            description = "tag 1",
            icon = "icone 1",
            weight = 98
        )

        val partner = Partner(
            id = 1,
            name = "Foo 1",
            description = "partner 1",
            link = "link.com",
            logo = "logo.png",
            contactType = "",
            buttonLabel = ""
        )

        val partnerDto = PartnerDto(
            id = partner.id,
            name = partner.name,
            description = partner.description,
            logo = partner.logo,
            link = partner.link,
            action = Action("", "", "")

        )

        val productTagDto = ProductTagDto(
            id = tag.id,
            title = tag.title,
            description = tag.description,
            icon = tag.icon,
            iconWhite = tag.iconWhite,
            iconOrange = tag.iconOrange,
            weight = tag.weight,
            highlight = true
        )

        val productOne = FinancialProduct(
            id = 1,
            title = "Foo 1",
            description = "Product 1",
            partners = setOf(partner),
            loan = setOf(loanTwo, loanThree),
            index = 4,
            category = PERSONAL_LOAN
        )

        val productOneDto = FinancialProductDto(
            id = productOne.id,
            title = productOne.title,
            description = productOne.description,
            category = productOne.category,
            tags = listOf(productTagDto),
            partners = setOf(partnerDto)

        )

        val productTwo = FinancialProduct(
            id = 2,
            title = "Foo 2",
            description = "Product 2",
            partners = setOf(partner),
            loan = setOf(loanTwo, loanThree),
            index = 1,
            category = TRUCK_SECURED_LOAN
        )

        val productTwoDto = FinancialProductDto(
            id = productTwo.id,
            title = productTwo.title,
            description = productTwo.description,
            partners = setOf(partnerDto),
            category = TRUCK_SECURED_LOAN,
            tags = listOf(productTagDto)
        )

        val productThree = FinancialProduct(
            id = 3,
            title = "Foo 3",
            description = "Product 3",
            partners = setOf(partner),
            loan = setOf(loanTwo, loanThree),
            index = 2,
            category = CAR_SECURED_LOAN
        )

        val productThreeDto = FinancialProductDto(
            id = productThree.id,
            title = productThree.title,
            description = productThree.description,
            partners = setOf(partnerDto),
            category = CAR_SECURED_LOAN,
            tags = listOf(productTagDto)
        )

        val productFour = FinancialProduct(
            id = 4,
            title = "Foo 4",
            description = "Product 4",
            partners = setOf(partner),
            loan = setOf(loanThree),
            index = 3,
            category = TRUCK_FINANCING
        )

        val productFourDto = FinancialProductDto(
            id = productFour.id,
            title = productFour.title,
            description = productFour.description,
            partners = setOf(partnerDto),
            category = TRUCK_FINANCING,
            tags = listOf(productTagDto)
        )

        val productFive = FinancialProduct(
            id = 5,
            title = "Foo 5",
            description = "Product 5",
            partners = setOf(),
            loan = setOf(),
            category = NOT_AVAILABLE
        )

        val productFiveDto = FinancialProductDto(
            id = productFive.id,
            title = productFive.title,
            description = productFive.description,
            category = NOT_AVAILABLE,
            tags = listOf(productTagDto),
            partners = setOf(partnerDto)
        )

        val productSix = FinancialProduct(
            id = 6,
            title = "Foo 6",
            description = "Product 6",
            partners = setOf(),
            loan = setOf(),
            category = NOT_AVAILABLE
        )

        val productSixDto = FinancialProductDto(
            id = productSix.id,
            title = productSix.title,
            description = productSix.description,
            partners = setOf(partnerDto),
            category = NOT_AVAILABLE,
            tags = listOf(productTagDto)
        )

        val financialProductOneTag = FinancialProductTag(
            id = 1L,
            financialProduct = productOne,
            productTag = tag,
            highlight = true
        )

        val financialProductTwoTag = FinancialProductTag(
            id = 2L,
            financialProduct = productTwo,
            productTag = tag,
            highlight = true
        )

        val financialProductThreeTag = FinancialProductTag(
            id = 3L,
            financialProduct = productThree,
            productTag = tag,
            highlight = true
        )

        val financialProductFourTag = FinancialProductTag(
            id = 4L,
            financialProduct = productFour,
            productTag = tag,
            highlight = true
        )

        whenever(loanRepository.saveAll(listOf(any()))).thenReturn(listOf(loanOne, loanTwo, loanThree))
        whenever(loanRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(listOf(loanOne, loanTwo, loanThree))
        whenever(reasonRepository.saveAll(listOf(any()))).thenReturn(
            listOf(
                reasonOne,
                reasonTwo,
                reasonThree,
                reasonFour,
                reasonFive,
                reasonSix,
                reasonSeven
            )
        )
        whenever(reasonRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(
            listOf(
                reasonOne,
                reasonTwo,
                reasonThree,
                reasonFour,
                reasonFive,
                reasonSix,
                reasonSeven
            )
        )
        whenever(productTagRepository.saveAll(listOf(any()))).thenReturn(listOf(tag))
        whenever(partnerRepository.saveAll(listOf(any()))).thenReturn(listOf(partner))
        whenever(financialProductRepository.saveAll(listOf(any()))).thenReturn(
            listOf(
                productOne,
                productTwo,
                productThree,
                productFour,
                productFive,
                productSix
            )
        )
        whenever(financialProductTagRepository.saveAll(listOf(any()))).thenReturn(
            listOf(
                financialProductOneTag,
                financialProductTwoTag,
                financialProductThreeTag,
                financialProductFourTag
            )
        )
        whenever(financialProductRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(
            listOf(
                productOne,
                productTwo,
                productThree,
                productFour,
                productFive,
                productSix
            )
        )
        whenever(financialProductService.mapTagToDtoBeta(any())).thenReturn(listOf(productTagDto))
        whenever(financialProductService.mapPartnerToDto(any())).thenReturn(setOf(partnerDto))
        whenever(
            financialProductService.mapFinancialProductToDto(
                productOne,
                listOf(productTagDto),
                setOf(partnerDto)
            )
        ).thenReturn(productOneDto)
        whenever(
            financialProductService.mapFinancialProductToDto(
                productTwo,
                listOf(productTagDto),
                setOf(partnerDto)
            )
        ).thenReturn(productTwoDto)
        whenever(
            financialProductService.mapFinancialProductToDto(
                productThree,
                listOf(productTagDto),
                setOf(partnerDto)
            )
        ).thenReturn(productThreeDto)
        whenever(
            financialProductService.mapFinancialProductToDto(
                productFour,
                listOf(productTagDto),
                setOf(partnerDto)
            )
        ).thenReturn(productFourDto)
        whenever(
            financialProductService.mapFinancialProductToDto(
                productFive,
                listOf(productTagDto),
                setOf(partnerDto)
            )
        ).thenReturn(productFiveDto)
        whenever(
            financialProductService.mapFinancialProductToDto(
                productSix,
                listOf(productTagDto),
                setOf(partnerDto)
            )
        ).thenReturn(productSixDto)
    }```
````

Comment: Is there any way to get a copy of the whole project or at least the relevant module that raised the compilation error? I would like to dig into the problem but i can not see a BlockExpression besides the function body. Maybe some of your models are causing this problem.

Comment: `Error type encountered: (org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.ErrorUtils$UninferredParameterTypeConstructor@d084bd5` may leed to a point where type inference failed within the compiler.

Comment: `getOrCreateCallGenerator(ExpressionCodegen.java:2945)` followed by `KotlinTypeMapper.writeGenericArguments(KotlinTypeMapper.kt:369)` indicates that this interence problem occurred while generating a call expression that has infered generic types. Reduces the problem down to `setOf()`, `listOf()` or the mock behaviour definitions

Comment: Additional Question: Does this problem occur while trying to compile it using the compiler within for example Intellij IDEA or caused by maven/gradle using the CLI?

Comment: Guys, I managed to solve the problem using mocking my objects by saving with the save method, and not with the saveAll method as I was trying. I was trying to save a list of objects with the saveAll method, with kotlin version 1.6 in intellij it was working. but with the deprecated version 1.3 no, I needed to save each object separately with the save method